# Como se cuando dispatch_async termina en swift

Tags: json, swift2

Estoy tratando de obtener varios archivos en formato `Json` con la libreria `Alamofire`, y luego estos json los tengo que guardar en una base de datos `sqlite` en formato `String`.

El problema es que me realiza la insercción en la base de datos antes de obtener el archivo `Json`.

Como puedo indicar que inserte en la base de datos unicamente si las funciones asíncronas han terminado, y sino que espere hasta que termine??

Os dejo un ejemplo de mi código:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
    var menuJson = String()
    var comerciosJson = String()
    var coloresJson = String()
    var textosJson = String()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        menuJson = self.getJson("http://url_al_archivo.json")
        print(menuJson)
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        comerciosJson = self.getJson("http://url_al_archivo.json")
        print(comerciosJson)
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        coloresJson = self.getJson("http://url_al_archivo.json")
        print(coloresJson)
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        textosJson = self.getJson("http://url_al_archivo.json")
        print(textosJson)
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print("1")
        print(menuJson)
        print("2")
        print(comerciosJson)
        print("3")
        print(coloresJson)
        print("4")
        print(textosJson)
        GestorDB.addConfiguracion(menuJson, comerciosJson: comerciosJson, coloresJson: coloresJson, textosJson: textosJson)
        let valores = GestorDB.getConfiguracion()
        while valores.next() == true {
            let menuJson  = valores.stringForColumn("menu").stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
            let comerciosJson  = valores.stringForColumn("comercios").stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
            let coloresJson  = valores.stringForColumn("colores").stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
            let textosJson  = valores.stringForColumn("textos").stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

            print("11")
            print(menuJson)
            print("22")
            print(comerciosJson)
            print("33")
            print(coloresJson)
            print("44")
            print(textosJson)

        }
    }
}
```

Y esta la función con la que obtengo el `Json`

```
func getJson(url: String) -> String {
    var responseString = String()
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { response in
        if let valorJson = response.data {
            let json = NSString(data: valorJson, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            responseString = json as! String
        }
    }
    return responseString
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no tienes nada claro como funciona `dispatch`. No puedes tener varios `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, solo uno. Una estructura correcta sería...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {

    // Código A
    // Código que es necesario ejecutar en otro hilo
    // normalmente en background

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        // Código B
        // Una vez acaba la ejecución del código A
        // se ejecuta este bloque

    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, no lo tenia muy claro como funcionaba. Pero sigue sin funcionar, se ejecuta el código b antes de que termine el código a @mhergon

Comment: Ten en cuenta que en el código A debe ir código que no se ejecute en background. Es decir, deben ser operaciones síncronas.